# Getting Error while reading a manual_test.csv file in Jupyter. (Data and warehouse mining, Machine Learning)

Tags: machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, logistic-regression, data-mining, data-warehouse

I am trying to run a cell in Jupyter notebook and getting permission error number 13. The code is

```
df_manual_testing = pd.concat([df_fake_manual_testing,df_true_manual_testing], axis = 0)
df_manual_testing.to_csv("manual_testing.csv")
```

The error which I am getting is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-f14a4d175882> in <module>
      1 df_manual_testing = pd.concat([df_fake_manual_testing,df_true_manual_testing], axis = 0)
----> 2 df_manual_testing.to_csv("manual_testing.csv")

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in to_csv(self, path_or_buf, sep, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, mode, encoding, compression, quoting, quotechar, line_terminator, chunksize, date_format, doublequote, escapechar, decimal)
   3202             decimal=decimal,
   3203         )
-> 3204         formatter.save()
   3205 
   3206         if path_or_buf is None:

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py in save(self)
    182             close = False
    183         else:
--> 184             f, handles = get_handle(
    185                 self.path_or_buf,
    186                 self.mode,

~\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text)
    426         if encoding:
    427             # Encoding
--> 428             f = open(path_or_buf, mode, encoding=encoding, newline="")
    429         elif is_text:
    430             # No explicit encoding

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'manual_testing.csv'
```

*I cannot understand how to change the permission of my file. I think so I will need to change it from root to user, but I am not sure exactly how to do this.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not interested in writing the csv file into the current working directory, you could simply specify the full path of a folder in which you are sure you have the permissions to write.

For example:

`df_manual_testing.to_csv("C:/Users/../manual_testing.csv")`

However, if you want to write in a particular folder, you can check from the terminal if you have the permissions to write here, using the command `ls -lh`. Eventually, you could change the permissions using the account of the owner of the folder, with the command `chmod 777 myfolder`.

If you need more information about file permissions, you could look at [this reference](https://www.linux.org/threads/file-permissions-chmod.4124/).